How does NetworkManager decide on default profile?
rg "Wired connection 1" /var/log/messages

1932:May  5 13:47:58 localhost NetworkManager[540]: <info>  [1714884478.7331] settings: (enp0s3): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
1949:May  5 13:47:59 localhost NetworkManager[540]: <info>  [1714884479.0191] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (2d5f9259-0521-3381-8da8-2ee6c0c27f47)
1951:May  5 13:47:59 localhost NetworkManager[540]: <info>  [1714884479.0248] device (enp0s3): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (2d5f9259-0521-3381-8da8-2ee6c0c27f47)
1965:May  5 13:47:59 localhost NetworkManager[540]: <info>  [1714884479.7903] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp0s3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS

I cannot find any profile that mentions 'Wired connection 1'. The following yields nothing.
find /etc/NetworkManager/ -name "*.nmconnection" -exec grep -l "Wired connection 1" {} \;

Even if I search the entire root fs for the connection ID I cannot find anything:
rg -l "2d5f9259-0521-3381-8da8-2ee6c0c27f47" /
/var/lib/NetworkManager/timestamps
/var/log/messages

How does NetworkManager know that DHCP is enabled on enp0s3 interface? Is it saved in some secret file with the key path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4"?
nmcli dev show

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:00:27:D2:61:6D
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.121/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     lo
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --



How does NetworkManager decide on default profile?

If none is present, it automatically creates a profile with DHCP selected as the method. See the description of no-auto-default in the NetworkManager.conf(5) manual page. The profile remains in memory until modified, at which point it would be written to disk.

How does NetworkManager know that DHCP is enabled on enp0s3 interface?

It doesn't. It assumes that DHCP is enabled, as the default choice.

Is it saved in some secret file with the key path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4"?

The assumption that wired connections without a profile should automatically get a DHCP profile is embedded in the /usr/bin/NetworkManager binary, as part of the compiled code.
